# How to change field level security of a field across all the profiles?

Tags: profile, field-level-security

Is there an option to edit field level security of field across all the profiles at once ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, go to the field's definition (e.g. Setup > Customize > Accounts > Fields > **Field Name**), then click on Set Field Level Security. This will allow you to customize the permissions for all profiles for that one field at once.

Comment: This has stopped working like this unfortunately...

Comment: @NEEA-CT It's working in my org. Can you be more specific?